# How to use 2 forms in a JSP page, one multipart Post and the other simple Post

Tags: mysql, forms, jsp, servlets

I want to use two forms inside a JSP page, in which one form is of `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and another is of simple `Post` method, but it's not working.  How should I deal with this?

1)

```
<form action="NewUserRegn" method="POST">
  <table class="mai">
      <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="entry">
               <tr class="entry">
                   <th class="entry" colspan="2">
                        Personal Details
                   </th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td class="entry">
                         Candidate's Name :<br>
                         <p>(As given in Matriculation Certificate)</p>
                   </td>
                   <td class="entry">
                         <input type="text" name="cdname" size="35" />
                   </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td class="entry">
                         Gender :
                   </td>
                   <td class="entry">
                       <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"  />Male
                       <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" />Female
                   </td>
                 </tr>
   </table>
  </form>
```

2)

```
  <form name="docs"
        action="NewUserRegn"
        method="POST" 
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <table class="mai">
    <tr>
     <td>
      <table class="entry">
        <tr>
           <th class="entry" colspan="2">
                Documents Upload
           </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td class="entry">
              Photograph : <input type="file" name="photo" accept="image/*"/>
           </td>
           <td class="entry">
              Signature : <input type="file" name="sign" accept="image/*"/>
           </td>
         </tr>
       </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>
             &nbsp;
         </td>
         <td>
             &nbsp;
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table class="mai">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="Recheck"
                           name="recheck" /></center>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                 </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
</form>
```

Comment: It is simple. Find Apache commons file upload, see its tutorial and implement it. You will find myriads of examples.

Comment: @Tiny When i am passing this value to store it in a mysql db then its error is coming as No value specified for parameter 4, but if i am removing the 2nd form then its working well

Comment: @LeosLiterak i m using Netbeans with Glassfish server

Comment: i have posted a part of the code here, its code is lengthy and has 26 fields in d table

Comment: <form name="docs" action="NewUserRegn" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table class="mai">
<tr>
<td>
<table>
<tr>
<th>
Documents Upload
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="file" name="photo" accept="image/*"/>
</td>
<td>
<input type="file" name="sign" accept="image/*"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<input type="submit" value="Recheck" name="recheck" /></center>
                       </td>
                        <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />                                        
                        </td>
                    </tr>
</table>
</form>'

Comment: @MdAltaf look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23464315/1066779) will help you.

Comment: You posted some HTML code but we do not know anything about java server side. How do you process the form? What problem do you face? If both forms are to be processed by single controller (servlet) they both must have enctype, otherwise it will be hard to distinguish the requests and parse them correctly. Use multipart/form-data and then read all fields with fileupload API.