# Upload image and information from textfields in the same servlet

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

this is my first time working with JSPs and servlets. I have a form in my JSP that has text input for name, description, etc of a product, and a field to upload an image. Everything is stored in a database (only the image path, though). I searched all over the web for how to achieve the image-thing and I finally got it working, but now it won't read the information from the textfields. That is, my variables are empty or null, even when they're supposed to get from the correct parameters.

This is my servlet:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

public class AgregaProd extends HttpServlet{
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
        String nombre = request.getParameter("nombre");
        String precio = request.getParameter("precio");
        String catalogo = request.getParameter("catalogo");
        String descripcion = request.getParameter("descripcion");
    try{
        String fileName="";
        String imagen="";
        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

         if (isMultipart) {
            FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator iterator = items.iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                FileItem imageFile = (FileItem) iterator.next();
                if(imageFile.getSize() > 100000){
                    return ;
                }
                if (!imageFile.isFormField()) {
                    fileName = imageFile.getName();
                    String fileBase = getServletContext().getInitParameter("IMAGE_FILEBASE");
                    File filePath  = new File(fileBase  + File.separator);
                    if (!filePath.exists()) {
                        boolean status = filePath.mkdirs();
                    }
                    File uploadedFile = new File(filePath + "/" + fileName);
                    imageFile.write(uploadedFile);
                    imagen=getServletContext().getInitParameter("imgsd")+"ComprasCool/imagenes/"+fileName;
                }
            }
        }

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/ComprasCool";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","jkDuhx+32");

        Statement stat = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Producto");
        RequestDispatcher disp = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/agregarproducto.jsp");

        int ide = 1;
        int idc = 0;

        switch(catalogo){
            case "hogar":
                idc=1;
                break;

            case "solares":
                idc=2;
                break;

            case "electronicos":
                idc=3;
                break;

            case "memorias":
                idc=4;
                break;

            case "accesorios":
                idc=5;
                break;
        }
        if(!rs.next()){
            stat.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Producto VALUES (\"" + ide + "\",\"" + nombre + "\",\"" + descripcion + "\"," + precio + ",\"" + imagen + "\",\"" + idc + "\");");
            disp = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/exito.jsp");
        } else {
            rs.last();
            ide=rs.getInt("idProducto")+1;
            stat.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Producto VALUES (\"" + ide + "\",\"" + nombre + "\",\"" + descripcion + "\"," + precio + ",\"" + imagen + "\",\"" + idc + "\");");
            disp = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/exito.jsp");
        }

        stat.close();
        con.close();

        if(disp!=null){
            disp.forward(request,response);
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

And this is my JSP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Compras Cool</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<div id="header">
<div id="logo"><a href="index.jsp"><img src="logo.gif" width="380" height="84" /></a>
</div>
<div id="search">
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="./buscar">
   <input type="text" name="searchbar" class="searchbar" id="searchbar"/>
   <input type="submit" name="searchbtn" class="searchbtn" id="searchbtn" value="Buscar" />
 </form>
  </div>
    <div id="userstuff"><a href="admin.jsp">logout</a>
</div>
<div id="nav"><a href="./hogarAdmin" target="_self" class="nav_link">Hogar</a> <a href="./solaresAdmin" target="_self" class="nav_link">Solares</a> <a href="./electronicosAdmin" target="_self" class="nav_link">Electronicos</a> <a href="./memoriasAdmin" target="_self" class="nav_link">Memorias</a> <a href="./accesoriosAdmin" target="_self" class="nav_link">Accesorios</a><a href="ordenes.jsp" target="_self" class="nav_link">Ordenes</a></div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="registro">
  <h1>Nuevo producto</h1>

  <form id="form2" name="form2" method="POST" action="./registraProducto" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>
      <label>Nombre:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="text" name="nombre" id="textfield4" size="20" />
      </label>
</p>
<p>
  <label>Precio:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="precio" id="textfield6" size="20"/>
  </label>
</p>
<p>
  <label>Catalogo:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
    <select name="catalogo" id="select" class="select">
      <option value="hogar">Hogar</option>
      <option value="solares">Solares</option>
      <option value="electronicos">Electronicos</option>
      <option value="memorias">Memorias</option>
      <option value="accesorios">Accesorios</option>
    </select>
</p>
<label>Descripcion:</label><p>
<textarea name="descripcion" class="des"></textarea>
<p><label>Imagen:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
<input type="file" name="fileName" value="" accept="image/*" runat="server">
<p></p>
<p align="right">
  <input name="registrobtn" type="submit" class="loginbtn" value="Agregar" />    
</form>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">&copy;Compras Cool 2014
<p>Acerca<font face="Arial"> | </font><a href="contacto.jsp">Contacto</a><font face="Arial"> | </font>Terminos y condiciones</p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [FileItem#getFieldName()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#getFieldName%28%29) to get name of input field and [FileItem#getString()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#getString%28%29) for value of input field.

**Solution:**

create two utilities methods one for regular input fields and second for File input field data. like:

```
// Process a regular form field
private void processFormField(FileItem item){
  if (item.isFormField()) {
     String name = item.getFieldName(); 
     String value = item.getString();
  }
}

// Process a file upload
private void processUploadedFile(FileItem imageFile){
   if (!imageFile.isFormField()) {
      //your existing file upload code.
   }
}
```

then, use above methods inside while loop to get data like:

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
FileItem item = iterator.next();

    if (item.isFormField()) {
        processFormField(item);
    } else {
        processUploadedFile(item);
    }
}
```

[Source](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html)